# Access class method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, class

There is a function in a class file name "User" in App_Code file. I need to access a function in the class

> public static string GetUserRole(string returnValue)

from javascript which is placed in a seprate .js file in the folder name "js"

Please help

Comment: var roleName = Users.GetUserRole("RoleName");

Comment: But this is providing me error. I need to get the return value from the function, please help

Comment: Exactly what is the context for this?  Where is the JavaScript running, exactly?

Comment: There are some validation already exists in the .js file, I need to append them based on the rolename. This .js file is placed in the JS folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to utilize page methods.  I better way is to use a web services or expose the function though some type of http get method or a [web service](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2007/10/calling-asmx-web-services-directly-from.html) .

Comment: Creating a web service will be difficult for me, because my boss don't want to go into creating other files for this. Can you help me with other solution, if possible. +1 for your quick answer.

Comment: Search for page methods javascript tutorial and you will find answers a plenty.

Answer (score 1):

[WebMethod]
public static string GetUserRole(string returnValue)

This guy explains it pretty good and has an example. http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/